# Wordpress - Displaying content inside the custom post's permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

In wordpress all posts have permalinks, and all non-custom posts will have the information displayed **in their permalink** which would let you see only that specific post.

However, I'm using Custom Post Types and I noticed that when I access their permalink, I will find no information other than the title.

Is there a way to put the custom post information inside the permalink, similiar to like using a custom template like when using custom pages.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your code which make your custom post @Bob

Comment: I used Advanced Custom Fields and Custom Post Types UI, there is no code, I just wanna add content to the custom post's permalink page